# How to setup adminer.php in local windows 7 ( if the db have no password)

Tags: mysql, adminer

I'm setting up a new adminer.php (version 4.7.1) file in local windows (version 7) system.

My local db have no password.

While open the adminer.php (version 4.7.1) file in local it shows below error,

```
Adminer does not support accessing a database without a password, more information.
```

I browse many place to overcome this problem. But I could not find that.

And I follow below steps to install the adminer file.

1. I'm download Adminer 4.7.1 file from https://www.adminer.org/en/.
2. After download move adminer-4.7.1.php file into my project folder.

If any customization need to setup adminer.php file in local?

Comment: So give `root` a password !!!

Comment: I try it. It does not work to me.

Comment: So show us what you did, and we will tell you how to correct what you did so it does work

Comment: Ok I add that php file in my Question

Comment: *"Ok I add that php file in my Question"* Don't ...it's like a 470 kB file.. Also everybody can download it if they want to.

Comment: Ok. I only download from https://www.adminer.org/en/. I didn't make any changes in this file.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was assuming this would be a little personal script NOT the whole of Adminer :) :)

Comment: If any possible to overcome this issue

Comment: Or simply add a password to `root` using the mysql command line processor

Comment: Or install WAMPServer and get Apache, Mysql, mariaDB, PHP, phpMyAdmin, Adminer, XDEBUG All installed configured and working at the click of an install

Comment: Ok i will try it.

Comment: sorry but iam out.. i not going to try and run that "obfuscated" source code on mine pc/server without knowing what that part does its mine common sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solving this issue using below steps.

1. Open the Wamp server file location
2. Add go to file_location\wamp\apps\adminerx.x.x folder
3. Inside of the adminer folder the adminerx.x.x.php file is there.

It is a suitable adminer file for current database file.

If you didnot have this (Adminer.php) file. You should follow below steps.

1. First download wamp server. The condition is the wamp server version is must to match your current working wamp server.
2. After downloading wamp to setup MySql database with your current db name like `root` and password like `root123` or `empty`.
3. After setup new wamp server in local goto the file_location\wamp\apps\adminerx.x.x folder.
4. And copied the adminerx.x.x.php file to your project location

In above I refered x.x.x in adminerx.x.x is version of the adminer. For example I use adminer4.6.2